# Parsing a bytes sequence from serialport using a Regex parser on Node.js

Tags: node.js, serial-port

On a Node.js script i have to read and interpret several bytes sequences from a serial port.

If a sequence starts with a specific header (0xff 0xff), its length will always be 24 bytes;
however, since there are other sequences with different lengths, i couldn't use a ByteLength parser with a specific length: therefore, i decided to try out a Regex parser.
The problem is i can't seem to make it read a 0xff value, using this code:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport')
const Regex = require('@serialport/parser-regex')

const serialComm = new SerialPort('COM1', { baudRate: 9600 })
const parser = new Regex({ encoding: 'hex', regex: /\xff/ })
serialComm.pipe(parser)

parser.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Received acceptable data!')
  console.log(data)
})
```

After several attempts, i changed the regex to `/\xff*/` so that any value would be displayed,
and instead of "ff" i'm receiving "efbfbd", like this:

```
Received acceptable data!
efbfbd
Received acceptable data!
efbfbd
Received acceptable data!
20
Received acceptable data!
00
Received acceptable data!
60
Received acceptable data!
12
Received acceptable data!
00
Received acceptable data!
04
Received acceptable data!
5e
[...]
```

What exactly am i supposed to do?
And if i can't read "ff" in hexadecimal code, isn't a hex encoding a bit worthless?
Is there another encoding i should use? Like something that uses extended ASCII, so that i can read values from 0 to 255?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end i used a Byte-length parser with a length of 1 and manually handled all bytes sequences one byte at a time, showing only complete sequences. Too bad, i was hoping for a more elegant solution, but i guess this one is the most efficient.